# Отправка PUT запроса из формы JPS

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, form, put

У меня есть jsp файл, где находится форма:

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="user" class="form-horizontal" method="${register ? 'post' : 'put'}"
                           enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${register ? 'register' : 'edit'}"
                           charset="utf-8" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

я использую taglib spring-a

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что из этой формы не отправляется **put** запрос.

В книге *Spring in action* написано, что для этого достаточно добавить следующий код:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic hiddenHttpMethodFilter = servletContext
            .addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter());
    hiddenHttpMethodFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
```

этот код находится в классе *WebApp* в методе *onStartup*:

```
public class WebApp implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringRootConfig.class);
...
```

В контроллере есть такой метод который должен обработать данный запрос:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/edit")
    public String updateProfile(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
...
```

**В чем может быть проблема???**
Хотя когда отправляю из этой же формы post запрос все работает.

Comment: а что в консоли браузера? и что в логах сервера?

Comment: Есть мнение, что метод put не поддерживается в html в принципе. Попробуйте выполнить put через javascript (ajax).

Comment: В браузере 405 ошибка: `Request method 'POST' not supported`

Comment: Sergey, я как раз-таки борюсь с этой проблемой. Я знаю, что put нельзя отправить с некоторых браузеров, но hiddenHttpMethodFilter помогает обойти его. Но пока у меня не получается. (я хочу без ajax попробовать)